# Suggestions modelling nested data sets that change over time

Tags: sql, nested-sets, temporal, temporal-database, nested-set-model

I am looking for suggestions on creating a temporal nested data set model. I am trying to improve performance for reading sections. I have a node tree of ~1million nodes, with frequent depths of 20+ nodes. The tree stores categories that can change over time, with the ability to enter future changes.

The current data structure is a temporal adjacent node model, modelling changes to the node tree over time is trivial with a simple data structure:

> Nodes
>   nodeID
>   [data]
>
> Edges
>   parentNodeId
>   childNodeId
>   validFromDate
>   validToDate

A nested data set makes for very fast read operations, but my current understanding of nested sets does not support changes over time to the tree

> Nodes
>   nodeId
>   left
>   right
>   [data]

One thought I had was to create a series of "nesting maps" which reflect the left/right values at given points in time, but this would mean recreating the entire node tree whenever a single change-over-time was modelled, which would make the size of the "Nests" dataset too large as changes are frequent.

> Nests
>   nodeId
>   left
>   right
>   validFromDate
>   validToDate

Has anyone created a temporal nested dataset model, or know any good resources on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

The following papers have investigated archiving multiple versioned nested data (a simple form of XML, but use of XML is not essential.)

http://xarch.sourceforge.net/

and see also some papers:

homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/opb/papers/TODS2004.pdf